# Word 2016- How to hide the 'Allow users to add and remove sections' feature in the Repeating Sections Properties' menu- VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

While the document is protected, how can I hide the '+' button at the bottom right hand corner of each repeating section so the user uses my code below to insert/add a repeating section?

My goal is for the user to use a macro to both add and delete repeating sections. Because there is no easy way to delete a selected repeating section when the document is protected, I don't want the user to be confused by having to click the '+' to add a section but then have use a macro located somewhere else to delete it.

```
Dim anchor_CC As ContentControl
    Set anchor_CC = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
        With anchor_CC
        .AllowInsertDeleteSection = True
        .RepeatingSectionItems(1).InsertItemAfter
         .AllowInsertDeleteSection = False
    End With
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply hide the Add button. You would need to disable adding and removing sections.

[image]

Then in your code you need to turn this setting on and off using the `AllowInsertDeleteSection` property of the content control, otherwise your code won't be able to add or delete any items either.

Comment: Thank you again!  I have edited my answer above and it works!